# Reshape features in rows intro columns python?

Tags: dataset, bigdata, reshape

My features are arranged in rows, Can anyone tell me please how can I transform them into columns with theirs corresponding times and values??
I mean each features has a set of corresponding times and values ..
a view example of   dataset is :

```
Feature                      TIME                     Value
    YAM_B55P113BDPMN  2015-06-14T04:05:18.000Z            0
    YAM_B55P113BDPMN  2015-06-14T04:06:18.000Z          Bad
    YAM_B55P113BDPMN  2015-06-14T04:10:08.000Z            0
    YAM_B55P113BDPMN  2015-06-14T04:13:18.000Z          Bad
    YAM_B55P113BDPMN  2015-06-14T04:26:28.000Z          Bad
    YAM_B55P113BDPMN  2015-06-14T04:31:48.000Z            0
    YAM_B55P113BDPMN  2015-06-14T05:07:28.0
        .
.......
   YAM_LIK13.SET.TTCI  2017-05-28T03:36:22.000Z          42
  YAM_LIK13.SET.TTCI  2017-05-28T07:23:31.000Z           42
  YAM_LIK13.SET.TTCI  2017-05-28T11:30:12.000Z           42
  YAM_LIK13.SET.TTCI  2017-05-29T03:16:42.000Z           42
  YAM_LIK13.SET.TTCI  2017-05-29T06:56:12.000Z           42
```

Comment: Please say what you are using for instance Pandas. Then this type of question may fit the Stack Overflow I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Reflecting the DataFrame over its main diagonal by writing rows as columns and vice-versa is known as "Transpose". if your pandas dataframe is named "df" then

```
df_transposed = df.T
```

Check out this 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html